# Can this be done in a single query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables in my database, in which `team1` and `team2` ids in `Matches` Table are equal to `team_id` in `TeamNames` Table.

also `group` in `Matches` Table is equal to `group_id` in `GroupNames` Table

*`Matches` Table*

```
 -----------------------------------
| team1 | team2 |  group  |  count  |
|   3   |   5   |   1     |    1    |
|   1   |   2   |   3     |    0    |
 -----------------------------------
```

*`GroupNames` Table*

```
 -----------------------
| group_id |    name    |
|     1    |   Finals   |
|     3    | Semi-Final |
 -----------------------
```

*`TeamName` Table*

```
 -----------------------
|  team_id |    name    |
|     5    |   Flowers  |
|     2    |   Rainbow  |
 -----------------------
```

What I need to get is:

`SELECT team1 , team1_name , team2 , team2_name , group , group_name WHERE count=1`

I tried joining tables, but as each of the team1 and team2 should be related to unique id in TeamName Table I failed, getting group name was easy, but I failed getting all the above in single query

Questions:

1. Is this possible in single query?
2. Can this be done using CodeIgniter's "[Active Record Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for q1:yes
Answer for q2:yes

Hope this may help you

```
    $this->db->from('Matches m');
    $this->db->select('m.team1,m.team2,m.group,m.count,tn1.name team1_name,tn2.name team2_name,gn.name group_name');
    $this->db->join('TeamName tn1','tn1.team_id = m.team1');
    $this->db->join('TeamName tn2','tn2.team_id = m.team2');
    $this->db->join('GroupNames gn','gn.group_id = m.group');
    $this->db->where('m.count',1);
    $results=$this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

yes. with INNER JOIN.

Here is an example to combine your three tables, if you want you can combine more.

```
SELECT * FROM matches ma INNER JOIN groups gr ON ma.groupid = gr.groupid INNER JOIN teams te ON ma.teamid = te.teamid WHERE ma.count = 1
```

Good luck!
Martin